# Failed to start X server

Tags: server, xorg, system-installation

Everything was ok until I get a dialog box stating:

> failed to start x server(your graphical interface) It might not be set
>   up correctly.  Do you want to view the X server output to diagnose the
>   problem.?

Yes or no gets me to the same end.

Then after that another box comes up telling me:

> the X server is now disabled. Restart GDM when it is configured
>   correctly

So ...how do I configure it.

Eventually I get " loading please wait"
...
some stuff

Then

```
ubuntu@ubuntu: ~$
```

with a blinking underscore

Answer (score 0):

Try to reconfigure X server:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
```

If it doesn't work  Try deleting ~/.config/monitors.xml

```
rm  ~/.config/monitors.xml
```

Comment: Thanks for editing my Question However I don't quite understand  where to edit or delete.  At the ubuntu@ubuntu curser?

Comment: yes my friend, open terminal and put the above command as copy/paste